# UPDATE db columns by removing absolute path and leaving file name in place

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have old legacy code that has been inserting file names with absolute path into db for decade. As you might have guessed, the path has changed many times and now I have column that contains file names in many different locations.
I would like to:

1. UPDATE this column to contain only file Name + extension
2. Change code to INSERT only file Name + extension from that point forward.
3. Change getter to get this new db column and expect it to be only file Name + extension and append full path to it retrieved from properties file

This is how `DistListName` column looks like in db right now:

```
DistListName

D:/REPOSITORY/DistributionListFiles/DistListFile-201312241253420087_1.csv
D:\docs\upload\DocAccess\Projects\ET\Distribution\ID_LE36A12-8-17-520-edited-6rows.csv
D:\docs\upload\Temp\5thdistributionList.csv
D:\docs\upload\DocAccess\Projects\ET\Distribution\APO-FPO - 3rows.csv
D:\docs\upload\Documents and Settings\mark\Desktop\4thdistributionList.csv
D:\docs\upload\Distribution\Printed Labels\2004 July\21 jul 04.csv
D:\docs\upload\200704191301190609\TestZipCode\4thdistributionList.csv
D:\docs\upload\Documents and Settings\patel\Desktop\attachments\distributionList_25.csv
D:\docs\upload\200704230652240281\Documents and Settings\omar\Desktop\ 1-1M-34 change\ID_01T06229100000R_070305102408.csv
D:\docs\upload\200704251628340140\TestZipCode\4thdistributionList.csv
b
NULL
C:\FILES\upload\201110041235580647\fakepath\ID_2 US locations2_100311a.csv
C:\FILES\upload\201111091019410135\Documents and Settings\leslo\Desktop\DPG CSV\Good CSVs\3 Jobs - FY-12-TESTING -.csv
```

I have SELECT statement that shows the end result, but I am not sure how to turn it into UPDATE statement:

```
select  
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', REPLACE(DistListName,'\','/')) > 0 THEN 
RIGHT(REPLACE(DistListName,'\','/'), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(REPLACE(DistListName,'\','/'))) -1)  ELSE DistListName END file_name
FROM myTable
```

The output:

```
DistListName

DistListFile-201312241253420087_1.csv
ID_LE36A12-8-17-520-edited-6rows.csv
5thdistributionList.csv
APO-FPO - 3rows.csv
4thdistributionList.csv
21 jul 04.csv
4thdistributionList.csv
distributionList_25.csv
ID_01T06229100000R_070305102408.csv
4thdistributionList.csv
b
NULL
ID_2 US locations2_100311a.csv
3 Jobs - FY-12-TESTING -.csv
```

And in my code, I will just expect file name + extension from db column:

```
public static String getUploadPath(String dbFileName)
{
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("fileLocations");
    return bundle.getString("DistributionListFilesPath") + dbFileName;
}

fileLocations.properties
    DistributionListFilesPath=D:/projectFiles/DistributionListFiles/
```

Can someone help me change this SELECT statement into UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your expression a bit.

**Example**

```
Select JustName = right(DistListName,charindex('\',reverse(replace(DistListName,'/','\'))+'\')-1)
 From  YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: And to make this an update, just change it to `UPDATE YourTable SET DistListName = right(DistListName,charindex('\',reverse(replace(DistListName,'/','\'))+'\')-1)`  P.S. You beat me @john-cappelletti

Comment: @LaughingVergil You are correct.  I tend not provide the actual update because I'd rather the OP validate the results prior to destroying the original data.